# fspecial not found in octave 3.2.3 Mac OSX. Do I have to install something else?

Tags: macos, octave

Am I missing something? Doc says that it must be present
Do I have to install something else?

Answer (score 4):

`fspecial` has been moved from the Octave core package to the extra package `octave-image`. Therefore you have to install it manually (e.g. `sudo apt-get install octave-image` on Ubuntu machines).

As pointed out by Woltan already, you could also copy the old source file from [this link](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/OctaveCode/fspecial.m) into your Octave path or directly into your Octave working directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/octaveinfo.html) link, `fspecial` is no longer available and/or needed for octave 3.
If you still should need it maybe including [this](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/OctaveCode/fspecial.m) in your octave path will help.

Comment: So, what should I use instead of fspecial in Octave3

Comment: Maybe it is possible to include the file and its dependencies to still use it. But I bet there is a reason why this method is no longer available. A reason however, that I am not aware of^^.